# Replace multiple instances of a sub-string with items in a list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, replace

I have a string like below:

```
e = "how are you how do you how are they how"
```

My expected output is:

```
out = "how1 are you how2 do you how3 are they how4"
```

I'm trying in the following way:

```
def givs(y,x):
    tt = []
    va = [i+1 for i in list(range(y.count(x)))]
    for i in va:
        tt.append(x+str(i))
    return tt

ls = givs(e, 'how')

ls = ['how1', 'how2', 'how3', 'how4']

fg = []
for i in e.split(' '):
    fg.append(i)

fg = ['how', 'are', 'you', 'how', 'do', 'you', 'how', 'are', 'they', 'how']
```

For every instance of 'how' in 'fg' I want to replace with items in 'ls' and finally use join function to get the required output.

```
expected_output = ['how1', 'are', 'you', 'how2', 'do', 'you', 'how3', 'are', 
                  'they', 'how4']
```

so that I can join the items by:

```
' '.join(expected_output)
```

to get:

```
out = "how1 are you how2 do you how3 are they how4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count

counter = count(1)

e = "how are you how do you how are they how"

result = ' '.join([w if w != "how" else w + str(next(counter)) for w in e.split()])

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
how1 are you how2 do you how3 are they how4
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make your code complex, just add a counter and add it to every "how". At the end make the new string.

```
e = "how are you how do you how are they how"
e_ok = ""
count = 1
for i in e.split():
    if i == "how":
        i = i+str(count)
        count += 1
    e_ok += i + " "
print(e_ok)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for your answer. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Regards.